# Picasso on Android does not load this image Uri

Tags: android, picasso, okhttp

This image Uri: http://d3lca4hm3yw4jx.cloudfront.net/medialibrary/Empire+2/photos_thumb/Empire2.jpg does not load in Picasso

It loads fine on browser.

```
Picasso.with(this)
    .load(Uri.parse(
        "http://d3lca4hm3yw4jx.cloudfront.net/medialibrary/Empire+2/photos_thumb/Empire2.jpg"))
    .fit()
    .error(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(iv, new Callback() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess() {

      }

      @Override
      public void onError() {
        Log.d("error", "error");
      }
    });
```

Set up:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
client.interceptors().add(logging);
Picasso.setSingletonInstance(new Picasso.Builder(this).downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(client))
    .memoryCache(new LruCache(50 * 1024 * 1024))
    .indicatorsEnabled(true)
    .loggingEnabled(true)
    .build());
```

libs used

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.7.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

the whole source can be seen here (Just one activity)

https://github.com/slashrootv200/PicassoImageUri/blob/master/app/src/main/java/in/curium/picassotest/picassotest/MainActivity.java

### Edit:

Added success log too. But I get a callback in error method.

```
03-20 00:59:11.112 27955-28089/in.curium.picassotest.picassotest D/OkHttp: --> GET http://d3lca4hm3yw4jx.cloudfront.net/medialibrary/Empire+2/photos_thumb/Empire2.jpg HTTP/1.1
03-20 00:59:11.112 27955-28089/in.curium.picassotest.picassotest D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: max-stale=2147483647, only-if-cached
03-20 00:59:11.112 27955-28089/in.curium.picassotest.picassotest D/OkHttp: --> END GET
03-20 00:59:11.112 27955-28089/in.curium.picassotest.picassotest D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP/1.1 504 Unsatisfiable Request (only-if-cached) (0ms)
03-20 00:59:11.112 27955-28089/in.curium.picassotest.picassotest D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (0-byte body)
```

Comment: Can you add a log for the success callback, to see if it is called?

Comment: Thanks for response. I just added success callback log but it did not work

Comment: The problem seems to come from this request header `Cache-Control: max-stale=2147483647, only-if-cached`. Try to call a vanilla Picasso to try, without the special initialization.

Comment: Thanks Philippe, I am trying that now

Comment: It's also related to cloudfront that hosts the image. I just tried another image with the same request header and it works fine.

Comment: Probably an error with MarkableInputStream https://github.com/square/picasso/pull/1280 https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/364

Comment: The web browser seems to load this image just fine. Yes I had tried other images and they work fine too.

Comment: @PhilippeA I tried with the vanilla thing, it did not fix it. Jared - the logs mentioned https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/364 do are not seen in my logs.

Comment: @JaredRummler you were correct. This got fixed when I updated the picasso lib to 2.6.0 (took their current development snapshot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets fixed by upgrading to Picasso version 2.6.0-SNAPSHOT from here. https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/squareup/picasso/picasso/2.6.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: The new version is invalid, I got an unresolved error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the `INTERNET` permission in your [manifest file](https://github.com/slashrootv200/PicassoImageUri/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml). Without it, your app (and thus picasso) cannot access internet.

Example:

```
<manifest package="in.curium.picassotest.picassotest"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
  android:name=".App"
 ...
```

Comment: Sorry about that I did add the permission but it does not work. I had quickly hosted this dirty app on github to share on this question, my actual app where this piece of code runs, loads other image uris well. It is just this Uri that has the problem

Comment: I see. I've just left another comment about the request header.